# window.open in PhoneGap app on iOS: This app is not allowed to query for scheme file

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-cli

I have a hybrid app developed with [DevExpress](http://js.devexpress.com) and [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).

I try to open a local jpeg image via

```
window.open('file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/.../image.jpg', '_system');
```

but it does not work (anymore) on iPhone and iPad (latest iOS 9 version), failing with the error `error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme file"`.

(The app downloaded the image beforehand via the Phonegap method `FileTransfer.download` to the folder that it got via `window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, ...)` method.)

**It works fine on Android, and it worked fine on iPhone as well a few weeks ago.** I think it might be related to the PhoneGap update due to an update of DevExtreme.

Before, I used **PhoneGap** 3.7.0, now I use **cli-5.2.0**.

I already found this question (https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q486439), which is similar, but it's already 2 years old and does not seem to solve my questions.

Using GapDebug, I see this in the log:

```
<Warning>: THREAD WARNING: ['InAppBrowser'] took '38.211914' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
<Warning>: THREAD WARNING: ['File'] took '26.509033' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
<Warning>: -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9425CCB6-77F7-4337-B37C-7DB577C2F6B4/Documents/myDocuments/a96e7238-a502-49e6-bcd3-186937afc3cb/camera_1458208164206.jpg" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme file"
```

It's some kind of **permission problem**, but what to add to the config.xml?

This is my config.xml:

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.devexpress.apptemplate" version="1.0" versionCode="1">
  <name>ApplicationTemplate</name>
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
  <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
  <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="60000" />
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
  <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
  <gap:plugin name="com.devexpress.plugins.devextremeaddon" version="1.0.1" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-ios-longpress-fix" version="1.1.0" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" version="0.3.6" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.3.3" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" version="0.5.0" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.6.0" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" version="0.3.6" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" version="0.2.16" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.15" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" version="2.1.0" source="npm" onload="true" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="1.0.0" onload="true" />
  <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <allow-intent href="*" />
</widget>
```

I even added the two lines

```
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <allow-intent href="*" />
```

according to https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist and it does not help.

I saw that Ionic, another hybrid framework, also mentions in their docs http://docs.ionic.io/docs/cordova-whitelist that there might be permission problems with newer Phonegap versions, such as the CLI versions, and that the above `<allow-navigation href="*" />` should be used - however it does not seem to help in my case.

**=== Update ===**

I created two tickets on Phonegap's & Cordova's github:

- https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/issues/413
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11027

**=== Update 2 ===**

As suggest below, I am now using https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2 instead, which works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem... I started using cordova-plugin-file-opener2 (github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2) to avoid the problem.

To solve the problem with white spaces I removed them from the targetPath:

```
targetPath = targetPath.replace(/ /g,'')
```

So my download/open code is like that:

```
$cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
  .then(function(result) {
    $cordovaFileOpener2.open(targetPath, mimeType)
  })
```

Comment: I wanted to keep the original name. I solved it by using encodeURI when downloading the file. https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2/issues/53

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 9 you have to config the urls you want to query (know if you can open them).

To do that you have to edit the info.plist and add the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`key and an array of strings with the schemes you want to query

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
 <string>file</string>
 <string>whatsapp</string>
 <string>...</string>
</array>
```

As you are using cordova, you can do that in a few different ways.

You can open Xcode project inside platforms/ios and edit the info.plist file, but the Xcode project is removed and recreated in some cases, and your changes will be lost.

Another option is to create a simple cordova plugin that just writes on the info.plist. To do that you have to use the config-file tag on the plugin.xml

```
<config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="LSApplicationQueriesSchemes">
    <array>
        <string>file</string> 
    </array>
</config-file>
```

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#platform

Third option is to use a hook, a hook is a script file (node, bash) that is executed, and you can use it to write on the info.plist
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html

Comment: I am working with DevExtreme (http://js.devexpress.com/) using Visual Studio (no XCode), which in turn uses PhoneGap in the end. There, I am just using some cordova plugins (whitelist for example). I don't have any info.plist file anywhere in my project. (Sorry, it's my first hybrid app, using Phonegap/Cordova). But maybe I forward your advice to the DevExtreme support. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Just a side note: the window.open worked fine on iOS 9 before in my project, it just does not work anymore since the recent PhoneGap version update.

Comment: I gave you 3 options, at least the plugin option should work for your case. The error you get appears when `canOpenURL` is used, maybe the previous version of cordova didn't use it and used `openURL` directly, using `openURL` will work a few times (I think 50) before start failing without error message. Or maybe devexpress was using Xcode 6, where you didn't need to do what I told you. To use plugins see https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18816

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Just fyi - the linked approach how to use plugins is 3 years old, it does not apply anymore. The current how-to is http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/VS_Integration/Packaging_Tools/#Set_Required_Plugins. 
I got it working now by using this plugin https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2.